# Ruby on Rails - using logger.info "hi" gives an undefined variable or method error, what to change/set?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging

I want to put something in the log, but I keep getting

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method 'logger' for Report:Class
```

I've tried

```
logger "hi"
logger 'hi'
logger.info 'hi'
Rails.logger "hi"
```

but I just get the above error.

I tried adding `config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)` to my `config/environments/development.rb` but that didn't help, still gettng the error.

I am running the method in `script/console`... but I exit and enter it each time to reload everything.

Comment: `Rails.logger.info 'hi'` works?

Comment: No, unfortunately it doesn't (added info above).

Comment: Can you provide the result of `p Rails` and `p Rails.logger` please?

Answer (score 3):

You have to use:

```
Rails.logger.info 'hi'
```

`Rails.logger` returns a logger instance, and by calling **info**, **warn**, **error** or **debug** on it with a message, this message is logged with the specified log level.

Within an *ActiveRecord* or *ActionController* instance you also have a *logger* convenience accessor available that returns `Rails.logger`.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have a variable or method called `logger` available in the scope you're executing that it won't magically exist. The `config` context is short-term, during initialization only.

`Rails.logger` is the global where you can usually access it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Rails logger outside of Rails models in at least version `2.3.X`.
You might be used to doing the following in your models or controllers:

```
logger.info "Some debugging info I want to see in my development log."
```

If you make a regular model that doesn’t inherit from `ActiveRecord`, though, you may see the following error:

> undefined local variable or method `logger' for #

The solution is to call Rails.logger.info (or debug, or warn) as follows:

```
Rails.logger.info "Some debugging info I want to see in my development log."
```